# illustration of overdispersion

Tags: r, glm, poisson

I am trying to plot best fitting poisson distribution over a histogram to show over-dispersion in data. I came across a piece of code: The first part creates an histogram and calculates a Poisson model. So far so good.

```
hist(patents$ncit, nclas=14,col="light blue",prob=T,
     xlab="Number of citations",ylab="",main="",
     cex.lab=1.5,cex.axis=1.3)

glm(formula = ncit ~ 1, family = poisson, data = patents)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.7513  -1.7513  -0.4604   0.3596   6.4405  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  0.42761    0.01164   36.72   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 13359  on 4808  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 13359  on 4808  degrees of freedom
AIC: 20350

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 6
```

In the second part of the code a best fitting poisson line is constructed. I do not understand **where does the `exp(0.32723))` comes from ?**

```
lines(0:14,dpois(0:14,exp(0.32723)),col="red",lwd=2)
```

Comment: Could you please include a sample of your data? Also, could you indicate where `exp(0.32723))` comes from (I cannot see it in your code)? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please include the link where you got the code from. At the moment your question is not reproducible and we can not help you.